# Why Are Certain Variables Undefined Inside This Function

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

Why are my first two variables undefined inside a function, when the third variable is defined:

HTML:

```
<p id="firstCard-el"></p>
<p id="secondCard-el"></p>
<button id="deal-btn">DEAL</button>
```

JS:

```
let firstCard = document.getElementById("firstCard-el");
let secondCard = document.getElementById("secondCard-el");
let dealButton = document.getElementById("deal-btn");

// generate randome number 1-11
function getRandomNum() {
  let ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
  console.log(ranNum);
}

// set cards to the random number
function deal() {
  firstCard = getRandomNum();
  secondCard = getRandomNum();

  console.log(firstCard);  //undefined
  console.log(secondCard); //undefined
  console.log(dealButton); //defined
}

dealButton.addEventListener("click", deal);
```

Comment: Your `getRandomNum()` function does not have a `return` statement.

Comment: Change `console.log(ranNum)` to `return ranNum`

Comment: Ahh, geez rookie mistake

Comment: Also the code is questionable in another way: you initialize `firstCard` and `secondCard` to refer to DOM elements, but then the function (tries to) set them to random numbers. If the desire is to set the content of those elements to be the random number, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

getRandomNum() needs to return a value if you're setting firstCard and secondCard equal to it.